# Spring Data JPA Error for 1.7.0.M1 query lookup strategy Exception

Tags: spring, jpa

I was trying to Integrate Spring Data JPA with custom queries added in my repository.The following error made me crazy

```
"You have defined query method in the repository 
 but you don't have no query lookupstrategy defined.
 The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!"
```

Can Anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Can you please post this as a Q and A dialog format. Ask a question regarding your problem (in the question section) then answer it in the answer section. That is perfectly legal. It's better this way for future readers :-)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion ,I have changed it ,please tick it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved when downgraded to 1.6.2.RELEASE

```
         <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.7.0.M1</version> -->
        <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade the spring-data-commons dependency to 1.9.0.RELEASE.

```
<!-- Spring Data JPA -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```