# Spring Data 1.7.0.RELEASE Query Strategy Error "The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am receiving the following error in a Spring Boot + jpa Hibernate with mysql using Repositories:

creating bean with name 'accountRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!

This did work with an older version of Spring data + jpa with just a spring mvc app and not a Spring Boot app.

The only solve I could find was somebody downgrading to spring-data 1.6.2.RELEASE ([Spring Data JPA Error for 1.7.0.M1 query lookup strategy Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111940/spring-data-jpa-error-for-1-7-0-m1-query-lookup-strategy-exception)) which I tried but it caused other conflicts probably because of my usage of a recent Spring Boot which has a recent Spring core which most likely has dependency collisions with the older version of spring-data.

Also I realize that specifying the default queryLookupStrategy is not necessary.

jpa config via Java Config is

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ranchtec.repository", queryLookupStrategy =       QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
@PropertySource({ "classpath:db.properties" })
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

@Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
private String driverClassName;
@Value("${jdbc.url}")
private String url;
@Value("${jpa.generateDdl}")
boolean jpaGenerateDdl;

// Hibernate specific
@Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
String hibernateDialect;
@Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
boolean hibernateShowSql;
@Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
String hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;

@Value("${jdbc.username}")
private String jdbcUsername;
@Value("${jdbc.password}")
private String jdbcPassword;

public PersistenceJPAConfig() {
}

@Autowired
org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

// beans

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(appDataSource());
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.ranchtec.domain" });

    final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        {
            setDatabasePlatform(hibernateDialect);
            setShowSql(hibernateShowSql);
            setGenerateDdl(jpaGenerateDdl);
            setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        }
    };
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionlProperties());
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource appDataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(jdbcUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

final Properties additionlProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            // use this to inject additional properties in the EntityManager
           // setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2ddlAuto);
            setProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        }
    };
}
```

Repository is generic:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

Account findById(Long id);
Account findByUserName(String userName);
List<Account> findAll();
}
```

Key deps:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include `spring-data-commons` wither higher version, eg `1.9.1.RELEASE`